# Understanding the Syntax of Overloaded Insertion / Extraction Operators (& Operator Placement)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Its been a few months since my last programming class (back in the spring) and I'm trying to do some practice with overloading operators of a class before I go back to class.  One thing I never quite understood was the placement of the & operator in the function name.  For example:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & Out, const Measurement & X)
```

The placement of the first & seems a bit odd because we usually place the reference operator in front of an object we want to become a reference, but the first one is placed before `operator <<`.  Is `operator <<` an object here?

I apologize, our professor never explained this syntax, just taught us not to question it, which I don't prefer.  I'd like to understand the syntax entirely.

EDIT: I've included the full function below.

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & Out, const Measurement & X)
{
    Out << "Inches : " << X.Inches;
    Out << "\nFeet   : " << X.Feet;
    Out << "\nMiles  : " << X.Miles;
    Out << "\n";

    return Out;
}
```

Comment: *The placement of the first & seems a bit odd because we usually place the reference operator in front of an object* -- Given that description, the `&` was not the reference operator, it was the `address-of` operator -- totally different meaning, even though the same symbol is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused because symbol `&` means different in different context:

```
int i, j;
int* ptr = &i;  // & is used with a variable, and it is operator "address-of"
int r = i & j;  // & is used with 2 variables and it is operator "bitwise-and"
int& ref = i;   // & is used with a type, not variable and it is not an operator anymore, 
                // it is type modifier, which says type is now not `int`
                // but reference to `int`
```

so in this code:

```
ostream& operator << ( ostream& Out, const Measurement& X);
```

`&` used with types `ostream` and `Measurement` and it modifies that types to references

Comment: This is a very enlightening response.  I was always under the opinion that the & operator got grouped with the actual variable name, which then modified it to a reference, but you are saying the & is actually modifies the type itself, and this is almost reflected in your coding style, as you placed the & next to int and not next to the variable name itself (even though the compiler doesn't see it any differently) - EX int& ref vs int &ref.  This style visually shows its affecting the type itself.  Which makes sense then because we are returning an ostream reference, Out in my case.  Correct?

Comment: By language rules & (and it is not operator in this case) is actually grouped with variable, ie `int & a, b;` - 'a' is refernce, but `b` is not, no matter where you put spaces. But I grouped them to the type in this example specially to make it clearer for your understanding. Personally in my practice I group them with variable as it follows language rules but I know developers who prefers to group that with type.

Comment: Thank you.  I need to break my habit of calling it an operator in this case.  It would only be an operator if its used bitwise of when obtaining and address of a pointer.  Thanks for reiterating that for me.  These are all things my professor never discussed.  He simply showed us where to place the syntax to get it to compile, but didn't explain the differences between the different case uses of &.  Its a bit frustrating to realize that it was never explained properly.

Answer (score 0):

> Is operator << an object here?

No. You probably confuse something from the syntax. The `&` actually belongs to the `std::ostream` type, and indicates a reference is returned from the function.

The reference in the return type actually indicates that the 1st parameters reference will be passed through, to allow chaining the calls to that operator overload. The implementation should look like this:

```
ostream & operator << (ostream & Out, const Measurement & X) {
   Out << X.x << " " << X.y;
   return Out; // <<<<<<<<< This is essential!
}
```

Thus you can call chained operations like

```
Measurment a;
// Do whatever with a
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

Comment: I edited my original to have the whole function there, where I did use a return statement.  So are we simply returning the address of Out?

Comment: In these overloaded functions, we are both printing the results to the screen and returning the object?

Comment: You're returning the same reference as the one passed in. As I mentioned, that's done to allow chaining the operator calls.

Comment: That makes sense, Out is being passed in by reference and is also being returned.  I never thought of the & in the function name referring to Out.  I would assume we would've just written something like 

return & Out; in the return statement instead